# UPDATE gridview row error

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, updatecommand

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="charges_gv_datasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="edited"
ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" SelectCommand="WITH relevant_ids AS (SELECT ir.result_id AS relevant_result_id FROM inspection_result_tbl ir) SELECT ir.charge_id, LISTAGG(ir.result_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ir.charge_id) AS result_ids, ch.charge_progress, ch.claim_verification, ch.hours_allowed, ch.sap_notification, ch.total_checked, ch.charge FROM inspection_result_tbl ir LEFT JOIN relevant_ids ON ir.result_id=relevant_ids.relevant_result_id LEFT JOIN charges_tbl ch ON ir.charge_id=ch.charge_id WHERE ir.charge_id IS NOT NULL AND ir.result_id=relevant_ids.relevant_result_id GROUP BY ir.charge_id, ch.charge_progress, ch.claim_verification, ch.hours_allowed, ch.sap_notification, ch.total_checked, ch.charge" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [charges_tbl] SET [CLAIM_VERIFICATION] = :claim_verification, [CHARGE_PROGRESS] = :charge_progress, [SAP_NOTIFICATION] = :sap_notification WHERE [CHARGE_ID] = :charge_id">

                             </asp:SqlDataSource>

                            <asp:GridView ID="charges_gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataSourceID="charges_gv_datasource" DataKeyNames="charge_id"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="805px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge ID" SortExpression="charge_id">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("charge_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("charge_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="charge_id" HeaderText="Charge ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />--%>
                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="result_ids" HeaderText="Result ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="resultid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("result_ids")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Checked" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="totalCheckedCT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("total_checked")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours Allowed" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="hoursAllowedCT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hours_allowed")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="chargeCT" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("charge")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="claim_verification" HeaderText="Claim Verification" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="charge_progress" HeaderText="Charge Progress" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="sap_notification" HeaderText="SAP Notification" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I have a data source and a grid view and I am trying to enable edit on the gridview rows. Everything works perfect, so i can click edit, the fields change to textboxes, the cancel and update buttons apear and work but if i change the values and click the update button I get the error :

**ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

Any ideas why? I have checked all the spellings in the updatecommand and it is all correct. Please help me.

Stack Trace:

```
[OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
]
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc) +488568
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.Bind(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, NativeBuffer parameterBuffer, OracleConnection connection, Boolean& mustRelease, SafeHandle& handleToBind) +1297
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals) +1204
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor) +656
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +158
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +2790646
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +4065616
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1350
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +626
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +110
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Comment: Can you let us know if you found a solution for this ? the below answer worked for us but if without installing/changing any tools work , it will be preferred

Answer (score 1):

There are many resons why this comes up. Sometimes because we don't use the Oracle tools and sometimes because of incorrect gridview markup.

since you do not require to update value of Column: `charge_id` , you cannot use a BoundField for the same unless you specify it in `DataKeyNames` property of `SqlDataSource`.

A BoundField if not specified in `DataKeyNames` ,generates  a bind variable which if not used in the update statement will result in ORA-01036. To avoid the error, either specify this field in `DataKeyNames`  property OR change this to a TemplateField and use Eval.so two possible cases I forsee:

1.) Set the `DataKeyNames` property of your SqlDataSource to `charge_id` .

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="charges_gv_datasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="edited"
 ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
 DataKeyNames="charge_id"
 SelectCommand="WITH relevant_ids AS (SELECT ir.result_id AS relevant_result_id 
 FROM inspection_result_tbl ir) SELECT ir.charge_id, ....." 
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE [charges_tbl] SET [CLAIM_VERIFICATION] = :claim_verification,...">
```

2.) If option 1 doesn't suits then :

Seeing your markup, definitely you have your `<EditItemTemplate>` in place as you haven't shown the same for many of `<asp:TemplateField>` items.

Make sure  then you put your `charge_id` column in an `<asp:TemplateField>`. Use `<asp:Lable>` so it won't be changed even in edit mode.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="charge_id" SortExpression="charge_id">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("charge_id") %>'></asp:Label>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("charge_id") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Seeing the Stack Trace provided Later On,** :
Better to Use Oracle Developer Tools (ODT) for VS and ODP.NET since they are better integrated with .NET and Oracle.

`ODP.NET` uses `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` namespace. `System.Data.OracleClient` belongs to the MS provider for Oracle. The connection string in the `web.config` needs to use the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` as shown below:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString1" 
 connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.104/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User    
 ID=system;Password=xxxxxx;"
 providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Go through this complete post for your reference: https://forums.oracle.com/message/2368331?#2366331http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=62196

Comment: I tried option 2 as it would not allow me to enter a datakeynames field in the sqldatasource. I changed the bound field to a template field and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Added stack trace to bottom of first post.

Comment: Ok. So probably not using oracle tools can be a reason possibly. See my edited answer. The end sectoion of the answer. Also I have provided you a reference link to check the same on Oracle forum.

Comment: I do not have access to installing ODP.net so this is not an option for me :(